# Nodejs: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Buenas tengo un error en Node que no entiendo porque sucede:

```
class HomeController {

getViewLogin(req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated())
        res.redirect('/index');
    res.render('singIn', {
        title: 'Login'
    });
}

getViewIndex(req, res, next){
    //console.log(req.user.nombres);
    //console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
    if(!req.isAuthenticated())
        res.redirect('/');
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Bienvenido',
        user: req.user
    });
}
}module.exports = HomeController;
```

La simplemente estoy redireccionando cuando el usuario está logueado, este codigo funciona pero me devuelve ese error.
Gracias.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dicho error pasa cuando se intenta **establecer cabeceras de la respuesta cuando esta ya ha sido enviada** al cliente. Trata de siempre usar `if/else` para definir un flujo estricto. Tu código no previene que `res.render` sea llamado después de redireccionar al `/index` o viceversea.

Además, no es necesario tener dos middlewares, simplemente basta con uno:

> **No renderices** desde un middleware. En su lugar, **rediecciona** hacia una ruta en donde se renderiza dicha vista.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    if (req.url.includes('/login') {
     res.redirect('/index');
    }
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias